# Python itertools combinations in distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I'm using `itertools.combinations` to match all the possible combinations of a list.

My list looks something like

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]
```

I understand how to get all the combinations, but if i want to use the distance formula on each combination how would I go about doing this?

I don't know how to use each individual combination in this matter.

Comment: What is your code so far? Simply loop over the output of `itertools.combinations()` to get each generated combination.

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop over the output of the `combinations()` function:

```
for xy1, xy2 in combinations(inputlist, 2):
    distance = calculate_distance(xy1, xy2)
```

This uses tuple unpacking; `combinations` produces tuples of two items each, and Python assigns these to the two names. The first combination produced is `([1, 2], [2, 3])`, but the loop assigns these to `xy1` (set to `[1, 2]` and `xy2` (set to `[2, 3]`) respectively.

Quick demo just printing:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> inputlist = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]
>>> for xy1, xy2 in combinations(inputlist, 2):
...     print(xy1, xy2)
... 
[1, 2] [2, 3]
[1, 2] [3, 4]
[1, 2] [4, 5]
[1, 2] [5, 6]
[2, 3] [3, 4]
[2, 3] [4, 5]
[2, 3] [5, 6]
[3, 4] [4, 5]
[3, 4] [5, 6]
[4, 5] [5, 6]
```

Comment: When mine forms combinations it looks like the following:
([1,2],[2,3])
How do i get into the form you have?

Comment: @BobDarren: Look carefully at the `for` loop; it uses tuple unpacking, there are *two* names to assign to. Python unpacks the `([1, 2], [2, 3])` tuple and assigns each element to a name, in order.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over combinations

```
def calculate_distance(points):
    [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]] = points
    return sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)

inputlist = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]
distances = [calculate_distance(points) for points in combinations(inputlist, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you later want to be able to access this data in a meaningful way I might suggest a dictionary comprehension. Similar to Martjin's solution, but with a little added context:

```
distance = {tuple(combo): distance(combo) for combo in combinations(inputlist, 2)}
```

The reason for the tuple casting is to make sure that the key of the dictionary is immutable.

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but a potential for the distance equation would be something like this:

```
def distance(combo):
    return math.sqrt(combo[0]**2+combo[1]**2)
```